# Opacity of my new page in ionic 3 app is set to 0.01 and no other page is opening after I opened this page

Tags: android, cordova, opacity, ionic3

When I opened a new page in my android app, nothing is shown. After opening this page I am unable to open any other page in the app.

When I inspected the code, I saw this page in html but it has opacity set to 0.01

```
<page-signature class="ion-page" style="z-index: 101; opacity: 0.01; -webkit-transform: translateY(40px) translateZ(0px);">
```

This error is only visible when I am running my app in android kit-kat versions. When I try to run this app in android marshmallow it's worked without any problem.

Can someone please tell me why my page has 0.01 opacity, Is this due to some kind error in that page, but no error is shown in console.

I have already shared my code in stackoverflow - [Ionic 3 app is not responding when I try to open a page that contains signature pad implemented using angular2-signaturepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413787/ionic-3-app-is-not-responding-when-i-try-to-open-a-page-that-contains-signature)

Comment: Can you please paste your code here?

Comment: You can see my codes in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45413787/ionic-3-app-is-not-responding-when-i-try-to-open-a-page-that-contains-signature